# Removing unique lines ending in a varialbe string

Tags: original-vim

Here is a sample of my file sorted.
The first part of the line is variable length, followed by `Jump to Record #: nnnnnn`

```
aaaaaa Jump to Record #: 10  
aaaaaa Jump to Record #: 22  
bbb Jump to Record #: 9  
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb Jump to Record #: 442  
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb Jump to Record #: 7  
eeeeee Jump to Record #: 4  
fff Jump to Record #: 7  
ttt Jump to Record #: 6  
zzzzzzzzzz Jump to Record #: 5  
zzzzzzzzzz Jump to Record #: 8
```

I am really trying to isolate the somewhat duplicate lines.

```
aaaaaa Jump to Record #: 10  
aaaaaa Jump to Record #: 22
```

I would like to remove the ones with a unique beginning like,

```
bbb Jump to Record #: 9  
eeeeee Jump to Record #: 4  
fff Jump to Record #: 7  
ttt Jump to Record #: 6
```

What I would like to end up with is,

```
aaaaaa Jump to Record #: 10  
aaaaaa Jump to Record #: 22  
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb Jump to Record #: 442  
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb Jump to Record #: 7  
zzzzzzzzzz Jump to Record #: 5  
zzzzzzzzzz Jump to Record #: 8
```

I have been searching for an answer for several days and no answer.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a regular expression to match two consecutive lines with matching prefixes. You can use a capture group `\(...\)` to match a pattern on the first line, then later use `\1` to match the exact same string on the second line. In a regexp, you can use `\n` to match the newline and continue matching the pattern on the following line.

For example, you could use the pattern below:

```
/^\(.* Jump to Record #:\) \d\+\n\1
```

You'll notice it will match the first line of each pair of lines with a repeated prefix.

Now, in order to *keep* only those lines, my suggestion is to delete them into a register, then clear the buffer and put the contents of the register, which will only contain the matching lines. (This procedure is a little bit complicated, but since you want to act on matching pairs of lines, it's hard to accomplish this more directly by matching the lines with unique prefixes instead.)

Let's use register `"a` for this operation.

We can start by clearing register `"a`, which you can do with command `qaq`. (The `q` command starts recording a macro into register `"a`, then the second `q` finishes the recording, without recording any commands, meaning the register ends up empty.)

Then you can run a `:g` (or `:global`) command matching the lines with the pattern and deleting them into register `"a`. We'll use the uppercase version of the register name, `A`. When writing to the uppercase version of a named register, Vim will *append* to the register, not overwrite it.

So we can use the following command:

```
:g/^\(.* Jump to Record #:\) \d\+\n\1/,+1d A
```

So the `:g` will first match the first line in each repeated pattern. Then the `,+1` will match a set of lines, ending at `1` line after (`+`) the initial matching line. Then it will execute the `:d` command (to *delete* lines) into register `"a`, appending to it since we're using the uppercase version of the register.

(Note also that if we had previously just used this same regexp, we don't need to type it again, we can simply use `:g//,+1d A`, since passing vim an empty regexp `//` will have vim use the most recent one.)

At this point, register `"a` has the contents we'd like to have. So we can open a new buffer, or delete the contents of the current one (e.g. `ggdG`), and finally we can put the contents of register `"a` with the lines we're interested in:

```
"ap
```

The `p` command (put) takes an optional register to put, where we can pass `"a` to use the named register where we stored the lines we're interested in.

There might be a blank newline or two at the beginning, but it should be trivial to just delete them after putting the contents we wanted.

Comment: Hi filbranden, thank you for answering my question so thoroughly. 
I have been trying to get your solution to work for the last hour and I keep getting a pattern not found message, by trying /^\(.* Jump to Record #:\) \d\+\n\1 at the command prompt.  



E486: Pattern not found:  ^\(.* Jump to Record #:\) \d\+\n\1  



Also entering the full command, g/^\(.* Jump to Record #:\) \d\+\n\1/,+1d A  
I get the "Pattern not found:" message.

Comment: @wgriffa You need backslashes around the parens for the groups, so it's `\(.* Jump to Record #:\)` etc. In Vim regexp `(` and `)` will match actual parentheses characters.

Comment: @wgriffa in your text there are spaces at the end, thus it doesn't match, add `\s*`: `^\(.* Jump to Record #:\) \d\+\s*\n\1`